Finding the Center of a Circle Inscribed in a Corner
I'm working on a project where I've come across the following problem, which I am stuck on.
Find point $Q$ in the following diagram, given points $P_0, P_1,$ and $P_2$, and length $r$:

(circle omitted from drawing for better clarity)
So far, I've tried to set up systems of equations in a couple of ways, but I wasn't able to solve any of them.

Find the loci of the points that have constant distant from $P_0P_1$. Then do the same thing for $P_1P_2$.

@Etemon duh, thank you! dunno how I missed that. If you post an answer I'll accept it (or I can post my own if u don't feel like it)

The distance from $P_1$ to the foot of either perpendicular from $Q$ is $r\cot\tfrac12\angle P_0P_1P_2$.


1- Finding by compass and right edge; consider the figure below:

Draw two circles with radius r on centers $P_0$ and $P_2$.

-Draww perpendiculars on $P_0P_1$ and $P_2P_1$ on point $P_0$ and $P_2$ en respectively.They intersect the circles at points C and B.

Draw parallel lines from point C and B with the lines $P_0P_1$ and $P_2P_1$, they intersect at Q which is wanted point.

2- Calculation if r is incircle radius: You may use Heron's formula to find the area of trianle first:
Let $P_0P_1=a$, $P_1P_2=b$ and $P_2P_0=c$ , we have:
$S=\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}$
where $p=\frac{a+b+c}2$
then use this formula:
$r=\frac S p$
$Cos (P_0P_1P_2=\alpha)= \frac {c^2-a^2-b^2}{a\cdot b}$
$P_1Q=\frac r{Sin \frac{\alpha}2}$

Thanks to @Etemon's comment, I managed to derive the following answer:
First, to shorten the algebra and make stuff faster to write, we establish the following variables:
\begin{align}
A &= P_0\\
B &= P_1\\
C &= P_2\\
D &= B-A\\
E &= C-B\\
N &= \frac{\left(D_y, -D_x\right)}{|D|}\\
M &= \frac{\left(E_y, -E_x\right)}{|E|}\\
K &= A \pm_1 rN\\
L &= B \pm_2 rM
\end{align}
Then, we can describe the locuses of points equidistant to $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{BC}$ parametrically via $K + Dt$ and $L + Es$ respectively. We equate those two, then solve for $s$ to get:
\begin{align}
s &= \frac{D_xK_y + D_yL_x - D_yK_x - D_xL_y}{D_xE_y - D_yE_x}\\
Q &= L + E\left(\frac{D_xK_y + D_yL_x - D_yK_x - D_xL_y}{D_xE_y - D_yE_x}\right)
\end{align}
Which we then plug back into $L + Es$ to get the point we wanted. This doesn't work when $\frac{E_y}{E_x} = \frac{D_y}{D_x}$ of course, but then it's pretty easy to figure out that $Q = L$.
This solution seems to always get the right answer for clockwise-oriented angles and using the $-$ in each $\pm$. I'm not really sure how to mathematically handle that ambiguity though.
